# Virtual machines containing RHadoop and the hadoop-streaming.jar

Tags: java, hadoop, virtualbox, hadoop-streaming, rhadoop

Getting a local test instance of Hadoop looks like a bit of a bear to configure, after consulting the following very clear, but still very complicated references:

- http://www.slideshare.net/ChicagoHUG/getting-started-with-r-hadoop-chug-20120815
- http://home.mit.bme.hu/~ikocsis/notes/2013/10/28/rhadoop-sandbox-with-the-cloudera-quickstart-vm/
- http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/
- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html

Are there recommended VMs that contain properly configured hadoop-streaming.jar and RHadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all RHadoop is [deprecated](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop). Use rhdfs, rhbase, rmr2, plyrmr, quickcheck. AFAIK, there is no VM which has Hadoop streaming and R installed. So, pick a VM from Cloudera/HortonWorks/MapR and then install [R](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/10/mapreduce-programming-in-r-using-hadoop.html) and then then the [required R packages](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/10/integrating-r-and-hadoop-using.html) on top of it.